# Validar campo en multiples componentes con FormGroup

Tags: angular, primeng

Tengo en mi componente principal

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-2 right"><label class="defaultLabel">Nombre: </label></div>
    <div class="col-3"><input type="text" formControlName="name1" pInputText /></div>
  </div>

 <app-description-form [form]="form"></app-description-form>
</form>


this.form = this.fb.group({
  name1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  name2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],

save(): void {
  console.log(this.form.value)
}
```

y en el segundo componente

```
<div class="grid" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="col-2 right"><label class="defaultLabel">Nombre 2: </label></div>
  <div class="col-3"><input type="text" formControlName="name2" pInputText /></div>
</div>

  @Input()
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

   }
```

Pero esto no me funciona correctamente, me gustaría en el this.form.value tener el valor de esos 2 campos

Comment: Pásale el form a través de un input a tu segundo componente y puedes hacer lo mismo que en el primero con un [formGroup] en un div.

Comment: he modificado como me indicas pero sigue sin funcioanr correctamente, es decir en el console.log this.form.value no me sale valor para name2

Answer (score 0):

Con tu codigo  construyendo el formulario desde **ngOnInit(){}** o desde el **constructor(){}** la consola me muestra los dos campos con el componente hijo formando parte del modulo principal. Por ejemplo nest en campo padre dan campo hijo consola muestra

```
{
    "name1": "nest",
    "name2": "dan"
}
```

Padre:

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}
 public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bindForm();
}
bindForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      name2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    })
save(): void {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
```

Vista Padre:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="col-2 right"><label class="defaultLabel">Nombre: </label></div>
    <div class="col-3"><input type="text" formControlName="name1" pInputText /></div>
  </div>
  <app-hijo-viewer  [form]="form"></app-hijo-viewer>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Hijo:

```
 @Input()
  form: FormGroup;
```

Vista Hijo:

```
<div class="grid" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="col-2 right"><label class="defaultLabel">Nombre 2: </label></div>
    <div class="col-3"><input type="text" formControlName="name2" pInputText /></div>
  </div>
```